# How to row bind data frames with same name from different subfolders in working directory

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have set my working directory to a directory containing two folders with three files each, and they have the same names as each other: SFM01_2, SFM05_2, 02M08_2. I want to row bind the files with the same name and bring all three combined data frames into the environment. The code I have tried so far works for the first file name in the list, but stops after that. Here is the code

```
setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/R_Directory/processing/test")
filelist <- list.files(recursive=TRUE)
list_of_all_sites <- c("SFM01_2", "SFM05_2", "02M08_2")

for (j in list_of_all_sites) {
  i_files <- which(str_detect(filelist, j))
  
  for (index in i_files){
    df_index <- read_csv(filelist[index])
    
    if (index == i_files[1]){
      df_site <- df_index
    } else {
      df_site <- bind_rows(df_site, df_index)
    }
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `{purrr}` package? It would be something like this:

```
library(purrr)

list_of_all_sites <- c("SFM01_2", "SFM05_2", "02M08_2")

list_of_all_dataframes <- map(
  list_of_all_sites,
  ~ list.files(pattern = .x, recursive = TRUE) %>%
    map_df(read_csv)
)
```

Comment: Thanks just did! It said I needed reputation to cast my vote, but that it was recorded. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one of two paths, both predicated on using `list.files(.., full.names=TRUE)`.

First, reproducible setup:

```r
dir.create("dir1")
dir.create("dir2")
write.csv(mtcars[1:2,], "dir1/SFM01_2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(mtcars[3:4,], "dir1/SFM05_2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(mtcars[5:6,], "dir1/02M08_2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(mtcars[7:8,], "dir2/SFM01_2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(mtcars[9:10,], "dir2/SFM05_2.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(mtcars[11:12,], "dir2/02M08_2.csv", row.names=FALSE)

files <- list.files(c("dir1", "dir2"), "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
files
# [1] "dir1/02M08_2.csv" "dir1/SFM01_2.csv" "dir1/SFM05_2.csv" "dir2/02M08_2.csv"
# [5] "dir2/SFM01_2.csv" "dir2/SFM05_2.csv"
```

### One Frame To Rule Them All

If all of the files are the same structure (same column names, regardless of the number of rows), then putting it all in one frame and doing analysis based on grouped operations (e.g., `dplyr::group_by` or `data.table`'s `[, by=]`).

```r
alldat <- lapply(setNames(nm = files), read.csv)
out1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, nm) transform(x, filename = nm), alldat, names(alldat)))
rownames(out1) <- NULL # I dislike the default row names here
out1
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb         filename
# 1  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 dir1/02M08_2.csv
# 2  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 dir1/02M08_2.csv
# 3  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 dir1/SFM01_2.csv
# 4  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 dir1/SFM01_2.csv
# 5  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 dir1/SFM05_2.csv
# 6  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 dir1/SFM05_2.csv
# 7  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 dir2/02M08_2.csv
# 8  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 dir2/02M08_2.csv
# 9  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 dir2/SFM01_2.csv
# 10 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 dir2/SFM01_2.csv
# 11 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 dir2/SFM05_2.csv
# 12 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 dir2/SFM05_2.csv
```

If the filename "base" name is important, then you can reassign this into the frame as well.

```r
basename(out1$filename)
#  [1] "02M08_2.csv" "02M08_2.csv" "SFM01_2.csv" "SFM01_2.csv" "SFM05_2.csv" "SFM05_2.csv" "02M08_2.csv" "02M08_2.csv" "SFM01_2.csv"
# [10] "SFM01_2.csv" "SFM05_2.csv" "SFM05_2.csv"
out1$basename <- basename(out1$filename)
```

Alternatives to the `do.call(rbind, ...)` are available, use either if you prefer.

```r
out1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(alldat, .id = "filename")
out1 <- data.table::rbindlist(alldat, idcol = "filename")
```

### Split By Name

If they are not the same structure, then let's split them before reading them in.

```r
split(files, basename(files))
# $`02M08_2.csv`
# [1] "dir1/02M08_2.csv" "dir2/02M08_2.csv"
# $SFM01_2.csv
# [1] "dir1/SFM01_2.csv" "dir2/SFM01_2.csv"
# $SFM05_2.csv
# [1] "dir1/SFM05_2.csv" "dir2/SFM05_2.csv"
lapply(split(files, basename(files)), function(fewerfiles) {
  out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(setNames(nm = fewerfiles), read.csv))
  rownames(out) <- NULL
  out
})
# $`02M08_2.csv`
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 2 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 3 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 4 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.40  0  0    3    3
# $SFM01_2.csv
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 4 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# $SFM05_2.csv
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 2 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 3 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 4 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to reproduce your example so I am taking a guess without being able to verify.

In your code the variable `df_site` gets overwritten in every step of the outer for loop. I would therefore believe that in the end it does not contain the content of the first file but of file three.

To fix your code insert the command `df_site <- list()` before the outer for loop. This will initialize `df_site` as an empty list that can then be populated step by step in the for loop. To achieve this replace `df_site` by `df_site[[j]]` everywhere inside the outer for loop.

```
df_site <- list()  
setwd("C:/Users/Christopher/Desktop/R_Directory/processing/test")
filelist <- list.files(recursive=TRUE)
list_of_all_sites <- c("SFM01_2", "SFM05_2", "02M08_2")

for (j in list_of_all_sites) {
  i_files <- which(str_detect(filelist, j))

  for (index in i_files){
    df_index <- read_csv(filelist[index])

    if (index == i_files[1]){
      df_site[[j]] <- df_index
    } else {
      df_site[[j]] <- bind_rows(df_site[[j]], df_index)
    }

  }

}
```

After this `df_site` will be a list with three components with each component holding the content of one unified file.